# text object not updating on screen when variable value changes

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I have some code that creates a button and code creating some text that is displayed on-screen. The goal is to have the button when clicked add 1 to the variable and have the changed reflected on screen (ie button is clicked the value on screen goes from 0 to 1 and then 1 to 2 and so on).

The button function:

```
def button(message, x, y, w, h, activeRGB, inactiveRGB, action=None): #example of color param for line 61/63 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #get location of mouse recorded by pygame
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, activeRGB, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] ==1 and action != None:
            if action == "countUP": 
                clickCounter+= 1
                print(str(clickCounter)) # print to check that the button actually changes the value 
                pygame.display.update()

    else: 
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactiveRGB, (x, y, w, h))

    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20) 
    textSurf, textRect = textBox(message, mediumText) 
    textRect.center = (  (x + (w/2)), y+(h/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

The logic I have so far

```
gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
clickCounter = str(clickCounter) 

textObject(clickCounter, black, mediumText, 200, 200) 

closeGame = False   

while not closeGame: # this keeps the window from shutting down 
    for thing in pygame.event.get(): 
        if thing.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            closeGame = True 

        print(thing)

    button("Click me!", 300, 300, 100, 100, blue, brightBlue, "countUP")
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)

gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
#logicloop()
```

The button function does appear to be changing the value of `clickCounter` but it is not reflected on screen. My guess was that there is a missing blit command or screen update, though nothing i've tried has worked.

For whatever reason when I had this block of code set up as a function that is then called, it ran without the `gameDisplay.fill(white)` or any of the other on screen elements appearing, how would I go about setting it up as a function to make adding more to the logic easier?

All of the code:

```
import pygame 

pygame.init() 

displayWidth = 700 
displayHeight = displayWidth 

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

black = (0, 0, 0) 
brightBlue = (0, 0, 225) 
blue = (0, 0, 255) 

white = (255, 255, 255) #predef colors to make temp rgb value coding easier 

closeGame = False 

mediumText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 70) #initalize font 
clickCounter = 0 

#def fontSize (pxsize):

    #pygame.font.Font("freesandsbold.ttf", pxsize)

def textObject (text, color, font, x, y):
    storedGenerate = font.render(text, 1, ((color))) 
    gameDisplay.blit(storedGenerate, (x,y)) 

def textBox(text, font): #purely for returning rectangle around font// used for btn function only, tObject for displaying text  

    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black) #swap black for rgb later
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def button(message, x, y, w, h, activeRGB, inactiveRGB, action=None): #example of color param for line 61/63 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #get location of mouse recorded by pygame
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    global clickCounter
    clickCounter = 0 

    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, activeRGB, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] ==1 and action != None:
            if action == "countUP": 
                clickCounter+= 1
                print(str(clickCounter)) 
                pygame.display.update()

    else: 
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactiveRGB, (x, y, w, h))

    #smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20) # constant has been declared, try deleting line when done w/ proj 
    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 20)
    textSurf, textRect = textBox(message, smallText) 
    textRect.center = (  (x + (w/2)), y+(h/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
clickCounter = str(clickCounter) 

textObject(clickCounter, black, mediumText, 200, 200) 

closeGame = False   

while not closeGame: # this keeps the window from shutting down 
    for thing in pygame.event.get(): 
        if thing.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            closeGame = True 

        print(thing)

    button("Click me!", 300, 300, 100, 100, blue, brightBlue, "countUP")
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)


gameDisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
#logicloop()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is, that the number value stored in `clickCounter` is converted to a string.
Delete:

<s>`lickCounter = str(clickCounter)`</s>

In the function `button`, the value of `clickCounter` is continuously set 0. Delete this, too:

```py
  def button(message, x, y, w, h, activeRGB, inactiveRGB, action=None):
      mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #get location of mouse recorded by pygame
      click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
      global clickCounter
      # clickCounter = 0 <------ delete

      # [...]
```

You missed to draw the changed text in the main loop. Before the text is drawn the "old" text has to be cleared. Continuously redraw the entire scene in the main loop of the application. 
This means the display has to be filled by the background color and the text and the button have to be redrawn:

```py
while not closeGame: # this keeps the window from shutting down 
    for thing in pygame.event.get(): 
        if thing.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            closeGame = True 

        print(thing)

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    button("Click me!", 300, 300, 100, 100, blue, brightBlue, "countUP")
    textObject(str(clickCounter), black, mediumText, 200, 200) 
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)
```

[image]

Comment: That works, and I understand what was wrong now. How can I stop the button from being held and increasing? There doesn't seem to be a cut and dry way to achieve that seeing as how ```pygame.mouse.get_pressed()``` works.